# How to Play 3gp Video in HTML5?

Tags: html, html5-video, 3gp

Playing a 3gp file with HTML5 does not work. I have Firefox 16 and Chromium Version 22 and the result I got is the following:

> No video with supported format and MIME type found.

Here's the code I used:

```
<video controls="controls">
<source src="rtsp://v2.cache2.c.youtube.com/CiQLENy73wIaGwlkcZfgin6szRMYDSANFEgGUghzdGFuZGFyZAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp" type="video/3gpp">
Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: As far as I know the 3GP plays in HTML5 player in Safari only due to the codecs used, so I would recommend to resing from using 3GP and have a file converter in order to make sure your video is playable

Comment: I see. How can I convert videos with PHP code? 3gp => mp4

Comment: This script would do: http://www.technoslab.in/2011/05/php-video-conversion-script.html

Comment: Just so people are aware, at least currently, doing this sort of thing actually seems to violate YouTubes terms of service https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms, in part II, point 10. it's stated that it is prohibited to "access any portion of any YouTube audiovisual content by any means other than use of a YouTube player or other video player expressly authorized by YouTube;"

Comment: It may be that Apache is not sending out the right heads for `3gp` files. Have you checked?

Answer (score 0):

Not supported out-of-the-box. To get an idea of what is supported take a look at this MDN page:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Video_codecs#common_codecs

One possible workaround could be converting the 3GP videos to something like MP4, eg with `ffmpeg -i video.3gp video.mp4` or to convert *all* `.3gp` to `.mp4` recursively from the current folder:

```bash
find . -type f -iname "*.3gp" -print -exec sh -c 'ffmpeg -i "${1}" -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac  "${1%.*}.mp4"' _ {} \;
```