# How to Embed 3gp Video in a PHP website?

Tags: php, video

I used HTML5 video tag to display video on my webpage but i can only play Mp4 video not 3gp format video , I tried changing type 'video/3gpp' but it's not playing 3gp format videos,

```
<video width="520" controls>
<source src="<?="uploads/observation/video/".$observation['video'];?>" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Need help to solve this , I tried Jwplayer , Flowplayer libraries too which also not supports 3gp format.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220019/how-to-play-3gp-video-in-html5

Comment: Thanks @Anant but there is no solution in that post.

Comment: [Convert it to one of the supported formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Supported_media_formats).

Answer (score 1):

You need to install some video player plugin to make the video able to be played in browser. (e.g. VLC , QuickTime)

However that  is difficult for Chrome, as now Chrome blocked for all video player that developed with NPAPI protocol.